# What's the best way to match strings in a file to case class in Scala?

Tags: regex, scala, recursion, case-class, fileparsing

We have a file that contains data that we want to match to a case class. I know enough to brute force it but looking for an idiomatic way in scala.

Given File:

```
#record
name:John Doe
age: 34

#record
name: Smith Holy
age: 33 

# some comment

#record
# another comment
name: Martin Fowler
age: 99
```

(field values on two lines are INVALID, e.g. name:John\n Smith should error)

And the case class

```
case class Record(name:String, age:Int)
```

I Want to return a Seq type such as Stream:

```
val records: Stream records
```

The couple of ideas i'm working with but so far haven't implemented is:

1. Remove all new lines and treat the whole file as one long string. Then grep match on the string "((?!name).)+((?!age).)+age:([\s\d]+)" and create a new object of my case class for each match but so far my regex foo is low and can't match around comments.
2. Recursive idea: Iterate through each line to find the first line that matches record, then recursively call the function to match name, then age. Tail recursively return `Some(new Record(cumulativeMap.get(name), cumulativeMap.get(age))` or `None` when hitting the next `record` after `name` (i.e. `age` was never encountered)
3. ?? Better Idea?

Thanks for reading! The file is more complicated than above but all rules are equal. For the curious: i'm trying to parse a custom M3U playlist file format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Parser Combinators](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Parser+Combinators--Getting+Started).

If you have the file format specification in BNF or can write one, then Scala can create a parser for you from those rules. This may be more robust than hand-made regex based parsers. It's certainly more "Scala".

Comment: I think the best Scala option here. In my actual work I have way too many fields to sit here and match regex for each of them. There's also header fields. I think this will be the way to go. I'll check this out.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [kantan.regex](https://github.com/nrinaudo/kantan.regex) for a fairly trivial regex based solution.

Without fancy shapeless derivation, you can write the following:

```
import kantan.regex._
import kantan.regex.implicits._

case class Record(name:String, age:Int) 
implicit val decoder = MatchDecoder.ordered(Record.apply _)
input.evalRegex[Record](rx"(?:name:\s*([^\n]+))\n(?:age:\s*([0-9]+))").toList
```

This yields:

```
List(Success(Record(John Doe,34)), Success(Record(Smith Holy,33)), Success(Record(Martin Fowler,99)))
```

Note that this solution requires you to hand-write `decoder`, but it can often be automatically derived. If you don't mind a shapeless dependency, you could simply write:

```
import kantan.regex._
import kantan.regex.implicits._
import kantan.regex.generic._

case class Record(name:String, age:Int) 
input.evalRegex[Record](rx"(?:name:\s*([^\n]+))\n(?:age:\s*([0-9]+))").toList
```

And get the exact same result.

Disclaimer: I'm the library's author.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience in Scala, but could these regexes work:

You could use `(?<=name:).*` to match name value, and `(?<=age:).*` to match the age value. If you use this, remove spaces in found matches, otherwise `name: bob` will match `bob` with a space before, you might not want that.

If `name:` or any other tag is in comment, or comment is after value, something will be matched. Please leave a comment if you want to avoid that.

Comment: No this works. I might use `sed` to remove any line starting with hash that is not a `#record`. The should remove all comments! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
Path file = Paths.get("file.txt");
val lines = Files.readAllLines(file, Charset.defaultCharset());

val records = lines.filter(s => s.startsWith("age:") || s.startsWith("name:"))
                   .grouped(2).toList.map {
  case List(a, b) => Record(a.replaceAll("name:", "").trim,
                            b.replaceAll("age:", "").trim.toInt)
}
```